# automatically submit a file in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

how would I automatically submit a form to a php file in jquery. I have this form right now:

```
    <form action = 'add.php' method='get'>
<input type='hidden' name = 'title' value='$title'>
</form>
```

I ask this because I want to use this to pass a post variable to another php file (ie...going from A to B to C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action = 'add.php' method='get' id="myform">
<input type='hidden' name = 'title' value='$title'>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myform').submit();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action = 'add.php' method='get' id="myform">
<input type='hidden' name = 'title' value='$title'>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("#myform").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: He wanted jQuery, not JavaScript.

Comment: @zgold if the answer is short whether it uses jQuery or not is irrelevant.

Comment: @zgold - Just to submit a form as soon as its available this is the simplest solution, juqery is not required.

Comment: Just sayin'... he specifically stated: "how would I automatically submit a form to a php file **in jquery**." We don't know enough to really tell if he might be using this to understand something else. To be quite frank, this question is a bit bland.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form action = 'add.php' method='get'>
<input type='hidden' name = 'title' value='$title'>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[action="add.php"][method="get"] input[type="hidden"][name="title"]').parent().submit();
});
</script>
```